# RailsInstaller applications will not let me update Ruby to most recent version

Tags: ruby, macos, railsinstaller

Since I installed RailsInstaller for Mac OSX 10.7, I'm not able to update Ruby. Here's the error I get:

> Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-O3 -I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include ./configure --prefix=/Users/kimbalin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247 --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
>   please read /Users/kimbalin/.rvm/log/1379210458_ruby-2.0.0-p247/configure.log
>   There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
>
> To proceed rvm requires a ruby-1.9|ruby-2 compatible ruby is installed.
>   We attempted to install ruby automatically but it failed.
>   Please install it manually (or a compatible alternative) to proceed.
>
> No MRI 1.9/2.0 ruby found, cannot build rbx.

How do I fix this and upgrade Ruby? I've downloaded Xcode and updated Jewelry Box, but I still get this error.